# Postgres COUNT FILTER syntax error - why?

Tags: postgresql, count, postgresql-9.1

can someone find me why this query is producing a syntax error? This is a simple ad database, it has categories and ads in them. The query is getting a list of ad categories, plus counts how many ads and how many active ads it has, the latter meaning ads not older than 2 weeks. PostgreSQL says:

*Syntax error at or near "(" LINE 5: FILTER(WHERE ads....^*

The other COUNT works just fine. I don't get what's its problem with the FILTER clause. Thanks!

```
    $data = pg_query($dbconn, 'SELECT categories.id,
                                  categories.name,
                                  COUNT(ads.id) AS ads_count,
                                  COUNT(ads.id) 
                                      FILTER (WHERE ads.date > '.strtotime('-2 weeks').') 
                                      AS ads_active_count
                           FROM erpatak.ads_categories AS categories
                           LEFT JOIN erpatak.ads AS ads ON ads.category = categories.id'
                           .$filter.'
                           GROUP BY categories.id, categories.name
                           ORDER BY name 
                           OFFSET '.$offset.' 
                           LIMIT '.$maxcount);
```

Comment: Do you see that in your error message there is no `ads.date` but instead there is `ads`

Comment: Do you mean the problem is that it doesn't know what ads.date is supposed to be?

Comment: Please attach full query string that is being sent to `pg_query` (without variables). Also, what's your Postgres server version?

Comment: This is the full query string. `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` can be omitted and `$filter` is currently an empty string. Server version is 9.1.

Comment: There was no `FILTER` clause in 9.1 so that's the problem.

Comment: Ah! That explains. Meanwhile I found this solution:
`COUNT(CASE WHEN ads.date > '.strtotime('-2 weeks').' THEN 1 END) AS ads_active_count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. As Kamil G. revealed to me, COUNT can't be FILTERed in version 9.1 which I have here. The solution is:

`COUNT(CASE WHEN ads.date > '.strtotime('-2 weeks').' THEN 1 END) AS ads_active_count`